# My select option changes to null in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I don't know how to change this, but whenever I use my select option, it always goes to null.

This is my HTML code,

```
<select type="number" class="footer" id="chooser" 
        ng-change="selectchange(selectedPage)" 
        ng-model="selectedPage" min="1"
        ng-options="x for x in pages">
    <option value="" selected="false" hidden>
</select>
```

Is there any reason it changes to null. Because when it changes it sends another request to angular.

What is the problem here, and how to solve it?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by null and where?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have 2-3 options in my select. So when I select one, say the second option, it takes that value and then automatically goes to a null value that I did not even put in the options. This results in my code getting another request as the value in the select options has been changed for a second time. I read somewhere that angular puts a null option in select but I didn't understand how to counter it.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have put pictures up for more context

Comment: edit your question with your js code you probably missing something there

Comment: Share your js code including `selectchange` and `console.log` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in html

```
<select class="footer" id="chooser" ng-change ="selectchange()" ng-model="selectedPage" ng-options="x in pages"></select>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.selectedPage = "1";
$scope.pages = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$scope.selectchange = function() {
  console.log("selectedPage changed to : ", $scope.selectedPage);
}
```

For more information read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 0):

You have set the option value to null and it always selected by selected tag. So it select null value every time, remove that option value and use ng-options to set the options in your selected box. No need to use option tag.

```
<select type="number" class="footer" id="chooser" 
    ng-change="selectchange(selectedPage)" 
    ng-model="selectedPage" min="1"
    ng-options="x for x in pages">
<-- <option value="" selected="false" hidden> -->   // remove this line
</select>
```